# python - When and how many times are global variables created

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

In my app I often query the db to get a list of columns in a table. The querying is obviously computationally and time expensive. I'd like to add this query to a config file so other modules from my app can reference the config file without having to query the db each time. However, I don't want to hardcode the columns to ensure cross-compatability with future databases which may not have the same columns.

**So my question is:**

If I have a `table_columns = db.query()` statement in my config file as a global variable. Will this statement be executed every time I import the config file? Or everytime I reference the variable? Or are all global variables from all modules initialised when the app is first set to run and so the query will only be called once?

Comment: why don't you try to figure this out yourself, by just putting a `print()` into the to be called and imported function-result?

Answer (score 1):

You code is being executed in certain order. Python is dynamically typed language. So, it executes the code in certain order e.g.

Let's say you have two modules:

```
main.py
settings.py
```

in `main.py` this is your code:

```
import settings


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = 4
    print(settings.a)
```

in `settings.py` you have such code:

```
a = 2
```

if you call `settings.py` directly with `python settings.py` then python will create object 'a' variable.

if you call `main.py` with python main.py then Python will `import settings` first because this is the first line in the executed module, creates variable `'a'` first because it imports `settings` module so it goes into it and runs all what is in it then it goes back to main and creates variable `b` and then it prints value of object `'a'` (variable named `'a'` referenced to value 2.)

I hope my explanation is correct. If not then please correct me. On a side note:

When it creates the object then it stores its name and its value and both are stored in two separate places in the memory. the name of the object then is referenced to the value of that object. I think it is worth to remember about it.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
#db_utils.py 
table_column=None  
def init_columns():  
   global table_column  
   table_column=db.query()
```

on other file

```
import db_utils
#call it one time dont forget to call it 
db_utils.init_columns()
#every time you want to access it without executing 
db_utils.table_column
```